# flexbox width 100% does not cover whole the page width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following CSS:

```
.turbineContainer{
        width: 50%;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        display: flex;
        
      }
      .turbineIcons{               
          background-color:white;           
          margin: 1em;
          height: 50px;
          width: 100px;
      }

      .container {
        display: flex;
       width: 100%;
      }
              
      .left-half {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        display: flex;
        background-color: #f7941d;
        flex: 1;
      }
      
      .right-half {
        background-color: #8d5022;
        flex: 1;
      }
```

here is my Html:

```
    <div class="container">
          <div class="left-half">
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
          <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>       
        </div> 
        <div class="right-half">
          here is the Right Panel             
          </div>
        </div>
```

I divided the page into two parts,left side and right side,i put the width 100% to cover whole the page width,but what is see is these two parts placed in the middle of the page,i have inclided a screenshot of what i get [image: The ScreenShot]

Comment: Which side should take the 100%?

Comment: @bertdida whole side,50% of page left and 50% of page right

Comment: That's how your code currently works https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-ritchie-dm0gf?file=/index.html.

Comment: @bertdida still the same issue,i have updated my question with a screenshot of what i get

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Could you show us  the `.turbineContainer` element in your html please. Just speculating,  since `.container` is eventually a child of `.turbineContainer` and `.turbineContainer` is set to `width: 50%;`.  `.container` will take `100%` of the `50%` occupied by `.turbineContainer`. Did you show us all of the relevant html and css? Best would be to provide us a runnable snipped reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the class `.container` you're using bootstrap right? it has a max-width which is why it isn't 100% width.

> Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are
> required when using our default grid system. Choose from a responsive,
> fixed-width container (meaning its max-width changes at each
> breakpoint) or fluid-width (meaning it’s 100% wide all the time).

Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Comment: im using FlexBox only,but when i put max-width:100% it works!

Comment: check which libraries you're loading in your project, bootstrap is one of them. Another way around this would be to use a class name that isn't used by bootstrap like .wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.container .left-half .turbineIcons{               
    background-color:white;           
    flex: 1;
    margin: 1em;
    min-width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
}
                  
.container .left-half {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f7941d;
    flex: 1;
}
          
.container .right-half {
    background-color: #8d5022;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-half">
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
        <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>       
    </div>
    <div class="right-half">here is the Right Panel</div></div>
```